# How to build Dockerfile with R & Java

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, rjava

I'm trying to build a Docker container that runs R with the package RJava. I have tried the following code:

```
# Install R version 3.6.3
FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.6.3

# Make ~/.R
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.R

# Install Ubuntu packages && then R packages
RUN install2.r --error \
         lubridate magrittr RPostgres DBI broom rlang rJava
```

However I get the following: installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status.

Can anyone help me with this. I'm thinking that maybe it is because Java is not installed. Does anyone know how to install Java on this docker container?

I've tried adding the following to my dockerfile as per another post I found however I get the error saying 'The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file:

```
# Install "software-properties-common" (for the "add-apt-repository")
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common

# Add the "JAVA" ppa
RUN add-apt-repository -y \
    ppa:webupd8team/java

# Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f;

# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

I'm new to docker and any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you instruct the container to install Java?

Comment: I've tried several ways of installing Java from other posts I've seen online but nothing has worked i.e. packages not found.

Comment: I've edited the post to give an example of what I've tried

Comment: Have you tried to use / copy from other containers who solved the same problem? https://hub.docker.com/r/cardcorp/r-java/dockerfile

Comment: I definitely suggest to use JDK from the OpenJDK by unpacking it inside certain location. Take a look here for the sample: https://gitlab.com/mkowsiak/converter-docker - There, you can find sample Docker file that will install any JDK you like (any OpenJDK to be precise) and you can easily configure it while building image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rocker` images are based on `debian`, not `ubuntu`. Specifically it is `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`. With that version, you can install `java` by installing the package `openjdk-11-jdk` via `apt` and you don't need to add any repositories for `openjdk-8-jdk`.

So a working dockerfile that installs `rJava`:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.6.3

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y liblzma-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libbz2-dev

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('rJava')"
```

Note: `liblzma-dev` and `libbz2-dev` are additional system dependencies for compiling `rJava`.